# How to only keep the first nth occurrence of a value in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan']
df['Date'] = ['2014-10-07', '2015-03-30', '2015-12-07', '2015-12-09', '2017-01-30', '2017-01-30', '2018-02-19', '2018-02-23', '2018-11-19', '2020-01-23']
df['Value'] = [2200, 75, 100, 22, 98, 0.36, 57, 29, 1026, 1296]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

```
    Name    Date    Value
0   Ankita  2014-10-07  2200.00
1   Ankita  2015-03-30  75.00
2   Ankita  2015-12-07  100.00
3   Ankita  2015-12-09  22.00
4   Ankita  2017-01-30  98.00
5   Yashvardhan 2017-01-30  0.36
6   Yashvardhan 2018-02-19  57.00
7   Yashvardhan 2018-02-23  29.00
8   Yashvardhan 2018-11-19  1026.00
9   Yashvardhan 2020-01-23  1296.00
```

How can I only keep the earliest 3 rows of each unique name? i.e. how can I have the data frame end up like this:

```
    Name    Date    Value
0   Ankita  2014-10-07  2200.00
1   Ankita  2015-03-30  75.00
2   Ankita  2015-12-07  100.00
5   Yashvardhan 2017-01-30  0.36
6   Yashvardhan 2018-02-19  57.00
7   Yashvardhan 2018-02-23  29.00
```

And how can I only keep the latest two rows of each unique name? i.e. how can I have the data frame end up like this:

```
    Name    Date    Value
3   Ankita  2015-12-09  22.00
4   Ankita  2017-01-30  98.00
8   Yashvardhan 2018-11-19  1026.00
9   Yashvardhan 2020-01-23  1296.00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) and [`GroupBy.tail()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html), as follows:

```
df.groupby('Name').head(3)

          Name       Date    Value
0       Ankita 2014-10-07  2200.00
1       Ankita 2015-03-30    75.00
2       Ankita 2015-12-07   100.00
5  Yashvardhan 2017-01-30     0.36
6  Yashvardhan 2018-02-19    57.00
7  Yashvardhan 2018-02-23    29.00
```

```
df.groupby('Name').tail(2)

          Name       Date   Value
3       Ankita 2015-12-09    22.0
4       Ankita 2017-01-30    98.0
8  Yashvardhan 2018-11-19  1026.0
9  Yashvardhan 2020-01-23  1296.0
```

Comment: damn, I was about to press 'Post'. unanswered questions are really short-lived ;)

Comment: @mozway  Haha, just by chance I'm faster this time.  Not so often  :D   Totally agreed. Unanswered questions are really short-lived.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way that I can get the latest two rows of each name by excluding the earliest three? Because it is possible that each person doesn't have the same number of rows (i.e. when Ankita has 5 entries while Yashvardhan has 7 entries). Thanks for your time!

Comment: @KaihuaHou - see the [pandas guide to indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). This answer has two components - first the groupby('Name'), then the operations to truncate the data. You can use `groupby('Name').apply(lambdd x: some_user_defined_function(x))` to apply whatever set of operations you'd like to to the data. So yeah you can definitely do this. You could try `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[3:].iloc[:2])` for what you're asking

Comment: @KaihuaHou  As long as a name has at least 5 rows, the last 2 rows and the first 3 rows are not overlapping.  So, your example of Ankita has 5 entries while Yashvardhan has 7 entries should be well supported by the codes here.   If you want to have them mutually exclusive just in case there are <= 4 rows, the code supplied by Michael in the comment above works well.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado  Thanks for helping me explaining to OP and providing the nice codes.  :-)